# sudo dscacheutil -flushcache = ?Invalid command

Tags: terminal

I'm getting the following response when I try and run `dscacheutil -flushcache`

> ?Invalid command

Comment: not sure if this it "too localized" since it *could* happen to others. I don't care either way if it's closed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I'm a complete idiot. I was running some `telnet` commands and forgot to `quit`

Comment: this answer saved me time and production server

Comment: Geez I did the same thing. Had a terminal session to a remote Linux server open. doh!